# Updating a database table from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psql

I have a web scraping script that adds data to a Postgres database. I am scraping a site where people sells used cars.

The final goal of my project is to find out which cars sells the fastest. So once every hour I will run a second script that reads the database table and updates the row if it was sold or not.

My idea was to do this with pandas dataframes (which I use initially to add new car ads).

After reading some examples and asking ChatGPT I have tried the following, but everything throws an error:

Trying `on_conflict`

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    updatedCars.to_sql(
      con = con,
      name = 'cars',
      if_exists = 'append',
      index_label = 'finn_code',
      on_conflict={'index': True, 'do_update': True, 'set_': updatedCars.columns.tolist()}
  )
```

Trying `if_row_exists`

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    updatedCars.to_sql(
      con = con,
      name = 'cars',
      if_exists = 'append',
      index_label = 'finn_code',
      if_row_exists='update'
  )
```

but both throw an error that they are not a method. Upon reading the Pandas documentation, I can't find any references to those commands either.

I am using sqlalchemy and psycopg2 and my Pandas version is 1.4.3.

I am questioning if I am trying to do something in an incorrect way, so I am very open to alternatives.

As mentioned, the goal is to read each row and update if the car listing as been sold or not.

this is the full logic that takes care of this.

```
def fetchCarsFromDatabase():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database="finnscraper",
        user="user",
        password="password",
    )

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = 'SELECT finn_code FROM cars;'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    finn_codes = []
    for row in result:
        finn_code = ''.join(str(element) for element in row)
        finn_codes.append(finn_code)
    return finn_codes


def updateCars():
    finn_codes = fetchCarsFromDatabase()
    urls = []
    for finn_code in finn_codes:
        url = 'https://www.finn.no/car/used/ad.html?finnkode=' + finn_code
        urls.append(url)
    allCars = getAllCars(urls)
    updatedCars = pd.DataFrame(allCars)
    updatedCars = updatedCars.rename(columns = {
    'Finn kode': 'finn_code',
    'Modell': 'model',
    'Totalpris': 'total_price',
    'Status': 'status',
    'Farge': 'color',
    'Hjuldrift': 'wheel_type',
    'Effekt': 'effect',
    'Sylindervolum': 'cylinder_volume',
    'Vekt': 'weight',
    'Antall seter': 'seats',
    'Karosseri': 'body',
    'Bilen står i': 'country_location',
    'Reg.nr.': 'registration',
    '1. gang registrert': 'first_registration_date',
    'Fargebeskrivelse': 'color_description',
    'Interiørfarge': 'interior_color',
    'Chassis nr. (VIN)': 'chassis_id',
    'Pris eks omreg': 'price_ex_registration',
    'Antall eiere': 'amount_of_owners',
    'Sist EU-godkjent': 'last_eu_approved_date',
    'Neste frist for EU-kontroll': 'next_eu_control_date'    
    })
    updatedCars = updatedCars.set_index('finn_code')

    engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@/finnscraper')
    with engine.connect() as con:
        updatedCars.to_sql(
            con = con,
            name = 'cars',
            if_exists = 'append',
        )
```